# SQL Server query with Superset not allowing to execute stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, apache-superset

I am trying to execute the following stored procedure in Superset SQL Editor:

```
Exec [CI_DW1].[Reports].[spGetPSBMFuelBidOfferVolume]
  @fromDate = '20220824',
  @toDate = '20220824'
```

But when I press 'Run Selection', it returns the following error:

> DB engine Error 
> Only SELECT statements are allowed against this database.

I can confirm that the user does have exec permission on the database, and successfully tested it by running as the user in SQL Server Management Studio.

My connection string is:

```
mssql+pyodbc://username:password@server:port/database?TrustServerCertificate=YES&driver=ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server&encrypt=yes
```

And I can use the connection to run select queries in superset successfully.

Has anyone else come across this before? Is it a limitation of superset or is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I don't know, but that's not a valid `EXEC` statement anyway https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a755f751e64d923d84fab0085dc040de, you can't have expressions in the parameter. Instead calculate them before in a variable, or do the calculation on the client side.

Comment: Sorry - you're right. I did change that when testing. I'll update the question to use the exec statement that did work!

Comment: It might be that Superset doesn't support Procedures; that was their stance back in [2018](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/4195#issuecomment-398103499). There's another Issue specific for SQL Server [here](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/2574). Their stance might have changed, but looking at the recent issues, it does seem that the tool relies on a `GetType` function returning `SELECT`; which an `EXEC` would not. They seem to recommend using a `SELECT * FROM (EXEC)` type query; which would mean using `OPENQUERY` or `OPENROWSET`. *Yuck*.

Comment: Maybe you would be better off creating some inline table value functions instead, as you *can* `SELECT` from those.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. That's a great suggestion. I think most of the procedures I want to use are easily replicated via select queries, so will do that, but I do like that idea of using table value functions for some other circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like superset does not allow you to call the stored proc, but there is a workaround you can use OpenQuery to get the result from a stored proc

[image]